# pandas groupby + transform gives shape mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a Pandas Dataframe with one column for the index of the row in the group. I now want to determine whether that row is in the beginning, middle, or end of the group based on this index. I wanted to apply a UDF that returns start (0) middle (1) or end(2) as output, and I want to save that output per row in a new column. Here is my UDF:

```
def add_position_within_group(group):
    length_of_group = group.max()
    three_lists = self.split_lists_into_three_parts([x for x in range(length_of_group)])
    result_list = []
    for x in group:
        if int(x) in three_lists[0]:
            result_list.append(0)
        elif int(x) in three_lists[1]:
            result_list.append(1)
        elif int(x) in three_lists[2]:
            result_list.append(2)
    return result_list
```

Here is the split_lists_into_three_parts method (tried and tested):

```
    def split_lists_into_three_parts(self, event_list): 
    k, m = divmod(len(event_list), 3)
    total_list = [event_list[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(3)]
    start_of_list = total_list[0]
    middle_of_list = total_list[1]
    end_of_list = total_list[2]
    return [start_of_list,middle_of_list,end_of_list]
```

Here is the line of code that groups the Dataframe and runs transform() which when called on a groupby, according to what I have read, iterates over all the groups and takes the column as a series as an argument and applies my UDF. It has to return a one-dimensional list or series the same size as the group.:

```
 compound_data_frame["position_in_sequence"] = compound_data_frame.groupby('patient_id')["group_index"].transform(self.add_position_within_group)
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
shape mismatch: value array of shape (79201,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (79202,)
```

I still can't figure out what kind of output my function has to have when passed to transform, or why I'm getting this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if ... elif ... elif ... else`?

Comment: good call, case might be that the result list is missing a value because of this

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm embarrassed to say this but here goes: in order to create the three lists of indices I use range(group.max()), which creates a range of the group-size -1. What I should have done is either used the group size or added 1 to group.max().